# Best sorting algorithm for large amounts of data

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a large amount of data that needs to be sorted, and it currently takes a long time. I would to use a better algorithm. I'm also relatively new at java so I would like it to be decently easy to implement, however that is not a requirement, as I can figure it out given enough time.

So what am I sorting? I thought it would be fun to make an application that could sort the pixels in an image by a certain value (red, green, blue, hue, saturation, brightness) so I'm working with integers and floats. And since its pixels in an image, there is usually hundreds of thousands of numbers that need to be sorted, sometimes even millions for HD pictures. I'm currently using some algorithm I thought up on my own, similar to selection sort. So yeah, its definitely not efficient.

Although it works, I would like something a little better, because it currently takes 3.5 hours to sort a 1920x1080 picture. I know that no matter what, the process isn't going to be fast, but it can at least be faster.

Comment: *I'm currently using some algorithm I thought up on my own, similar to selection sort.* Any particular reason you haven't posted the algorithm. Or compared it with quicksort or merge sort?

Comment: Have you tried using a sorting algorithm built in to java. Something like ```Arrays.sort()``` or streaming the image and sorting the stream itself? They will be the fastest you can probably do with very little effort.

Comment: you can try quick sort algorithm, The time complexity of Quicksort is O(n log n) in the best case, O(n log n) in the average case, and O(n^2) in the worst case.

Comment: For sorting by RGB values, [Bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) or [Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) could be appropriate.

Comment: Mate ... you need to read a Data Structures and Algorithms text book.  Or maybe read all of the material on Wikipedia about sorting.

Comment: So, I did a quick test and I was able to sort a image 1920x1200 (6,912,000 bytes/pixels) in rough 32 milliseconds using `Arrays.sort` ... but I could be missing something